# appending svg images produces rastered image

Tags: svg, graphics, imagemagick, raster, inkscape

I'm trying to concatenate svg images to produce an output svg image like so

```
convert -append in1.svg in2.svg output.svg
```

which I got from https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick

[image]
However, this produces a rastered image (on right), which is not what I need.  The effect is more noticeable if you click on the image.

How can I append SVG images without the rastering effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a python script which appends SVG images exactly how I wanted.

https://github.com/astraw/svg_stack

the example command line usage is:

```
python svg_stack-master/svg_stack.py --direction=v --margin=0 in1.svg in2.svg  > out.svg
```

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick is a raster-image processor.  To produce a new SVG image from two SVG images you need an SVG editor instead.

Comment: Are we talking **Inkscape**, or do you have any better suggestions to share please?

Comment: I don't see how to do this in inkscape, perhaps there is a package/command that can do what convert/imagemagick does?

Comment: I'd probably use a text editor or some kind of `sed` script, but that's just me.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson how could I append the SVG images with a sed script? I have only recently discovered the SVG format